# how to execute AT commands using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how to use AT+CLCC command in c# and how to monitor responses in a console ?
I tried with following code. But I couldn't get progress.This is what I have tried so far.It doesn't give any response.

This is my code :

```
_serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CLCC");

string responce = "";
responce = responce + _serialPort.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Check this......:" + responce);
```

how should i do it?

Answer (score 2):

I lost a couple of days on this a long time ago.

Use the DataReceived event to receive data from a serial port.

[SerialPort.DataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx)

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for your reply...I tried what you said..But as a result it gives only outgoing phone number..But i want output as the format-->+CLCC: <id1>,<dir>,<stat>,<mode>,<mpty>[,<number>,<type>[,<alpha>[,<priority>]]]